# Symfony templates corrupting data

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I've discovered that when I pass doctrine entities to our PHP templates, the designer can start calling setters and change the data. This is no big deal normally except there are pages that perform sub-requests so these changes are being seen by the controller and have the potential to be saved to the database (the identity map pattern returns the object rather than refreshing from storage)!

Is there any way to prevent the templates from changing the data?

(I've tried detaching entities before passing them but that makes the doctrine proxies not return data. I really don't want to lose the lazy loading)

Comment: I don't see a single reason to directly pass Doctrine Entities to the template engine.

You should copy the data you need to render the page in some array and the return this array at the end of the action module. You can also avoid the copy step if you use array hydration (instead of the object one).

Comment: @spider: The lazy loading was my entire motivation for passing the objects.

Comment: Uhm, I still doesn't see the point. Why you need lazy loading while rendering the page? It's what the "control" part of the "MVC" paradigm is there for: retrieve data from the model, prepare data for the "view". The template engine is the "view" part and should just have to render the data.

Comment: @spider: Yes that's a good point. Thanks for sharing your thoughts on the matter. If you make it an answer I can accept it. I've seen others pass entity objects and this answer will help them as well.

Comment: @spider: Could you please make your comment an answer as it's the answer I feel is best? I don't want it ending up where I write and accept the answer myself. That wouldn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the deferred explicit change tracking policy:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html

Only entities which you explicitly persist will be considered for updating.  So incidental updates done in a template will not be saved.

I suppose you could also try the Notify policy and, with a bit of magic, disable the notify senders to make your entities basically read only.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already use `deferred explicit` but that doesn't change my issue because if I need to persist something that was passed to the view, then I'm in the same boat as before. I'll be using spider's advice which is "I don't see a single reason to directly pass Doctrine Entities to the template engine."

Comment: That is fine.  I'm not so sure about this "don't pass entities" argument.  Seems kind of silly.  The real issue, to me, is why are you  persisting entities in embedded controllers?  Seems like all database changes should be made before the master template gets kicked off.  But that is just me and you might have a perfectly valid use case.